# Generating URI's from files in a File class in Java FX?

Tags: java, javafx, uri

I'm writing code for a music player in Java FX, I use the `MediaPlayer` class, which is initialized by a `Media` class. So far I think that the sources for the Media constructors must be **`URI`** in Strings, so I've writen this code for adding a list of song files to a playlist and so playing such list:

```
public void setPlaylist (List<File> lista) {

    songsList.clear();
    for (File s : lista) {
        songsList.add(s.toURI());
    }
}
```

This works fine. However, when I want to get a File containing the path of a folder, and inputing each file's name in URI format I get some trouble, this is what I've tried so far:

```
public void setPlaylist (File folder) {

    songsList.clear();
    for (String s : folder.list()) {
        try {
            songsList.add(new URI("file:///" + (folder + "\\" + s).replace("\\", "/").replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlayList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error logs like this:

> SEVERE: null java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at
>   index 78:
>   file:///C:/Users/Diego%20Aguilar/Music/3%20Grandes%20de%20la%20Banda/AlbumArt_{9AEABE24-F5A2-441C-A71A-D061E000A9BA}_Large.jpg

Comment: can u elaborate more on the trouble part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `File#toURI()` as you were using before to avoid running into encoding issues and make use of a `FilenameFilter` to restrict the list to media files only. Here's how the code would look then.

```
public void setPlaylist (File folder) {
    songsList.clear();
    File[] musicFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".m4a"));
        }
    });
    for (File file : musicFiles) {
        songsList.add(file.toURI());
    }
}
```

See JavaDocs: [FilenameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html), [File#toURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI%28%29)

Comment: You're passing the `FilenameFilter` to `listFiles()` which would internally invoke `accept()` itself. You just provide the implementation and the File API would automatically make a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `String s : folder.list()` use `File s : folder.listFiles()` ... then use the URL from the files.

Comment: How could I get the extension of each file, by evalauating wether its String value ends with `.*`?

Comment: A common way to do that is to use a Filter on the listFiles(filter...) and the Filter will tell you the File being checked. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html and use some logic on `File.getName()` when the file is being accepted by the Filter, and only accept the files with the correct extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Your file URI contains an angular bracket `{`, which is causing `SEVERE: null java.net.URISyntaxException`

You need to have a valid file path to create a proper URI.

Here is the link to [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for referring what is allowed and what is not allowed in a URL.